# Flutter how to change theme with BLoC and set system theme

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I use Flutter bloc in my main.dart to check user auth. Right now there is no theme selection in my application, it is selected programmatically depending on the theme on the device. I want my AuthBloc to check and set the theme that the user has set when the app starts. I have a theme selection page in which the user can select a theme, by default it should be system, you can also choose light and dark.
How can I implement this in my AuthBloc?
My main.dart

```
 return BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(authRepo: AuthRepo()),
          child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                print(state);
                return MaterialApp(
                navigatorKey: navKey,
                title: 'YiwuMart',
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: lightTheme,
                darkTheme: darkTheme,
                home: MainScreen(
                  key: scakey,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
```

My ThemeChange screen

```
bool isSystemTheme = true;
  bool isLightTheme = false;
  bool isDarkTheme = false;

  Row _buildThemeRow(String themeName, bool isSelected) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: 5.h),
        Text(themeName, style: TextStyles.bodyStyle),
        const Spacer(),
        if (isSelected)
          const Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Colors.grey,
            size: 15,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Выбор темы'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: REdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: REdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSystemTheme = true;
                          isLightTheme = false;
                          isDarkTheme = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: _buildThemeRow('Системная', isSystemTheme),
                    ),
                    const Divider(),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSystemTheme = false;
                          isLightTheme = true;
                          isDarkTheme = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: _buildThemeRow('Светлая', isLightTheme),
                    ),
                    const Divider(),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSystemTheme = false;
                          isLightTheme = false;
                          isDarkTheme = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: _buildThemeRow('Темная', isDarkTheme),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

My AuthBloc:

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AbstractAuth authRepo;
  late StreamSubscription _authenticationStatusSubscription;

  AuthBloc({required this.authRepo}) : super(AuthInitial()) {
    authRepo.getCookie();
    authRepo.getFirebaseToken();
    _checkAuthenticationStatus();
    on<LoggedIn>((event, emit) {
      emit(Authenticated(token: event.token));
    });
    on<LogoutEvent>((event, emit) async {});
    on<LoginEvent>((event, emit) async {});
    on<RegistrationEvent>((event, emit) async {});
  }

  void _checkAuthenticationStatus() async {
    final isAuthenticated = await authRepo.getToken();
    final isAuth = await Func().getInitParams();
    if (isAuth.statusCode == 200) {
      add(LoggedIn(token: isAuthenticated));
    } else {
      add(LogoutEvent());
    }
    _authenticationStatusSubscription =
        Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 30)).listen((_) async {
      final isAuthenticated = await authRepo.getToken();
      final isAuth = await Func().getInitParams();
      Func().getUnreadCount();
      if (isAuth.statusCode == 200) {
        add(LoggedIn(token: isAuthenticated));
      } else {
        add(LogoutEvent());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _authenticationStatusSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      final isAuthenticated = await authRepo.getToken();
      if (isAuthenticated != '') {
        yield Authenticated(token: isAuthenticated.toString());
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated(token: isAuthenticated.toString());
      }
    } else if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield Authenticated(token: event.token);
    } else if (event is LogoutEvent) {
      yield Unauthenticated(token: '');
    } else if (event is LoginEvent) {
      final data =
          await authRepo.login(event.email, event.password, event.context);
      if (data['api_token'] != '') {
        yield Authenticated(token: data['api_token']);
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated(token: 'token');
      }
    }
  }
}
// event 
abstract class AuthEvent {}

class AppStarted extends AuthEvent {}

class LoggedIn extends AuthEvent {
  final String token;

  LoggedIn({required this.token});
}

class LogoutEvent extends AuthEvent {}

class LoginEvent extends AuthEvent {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String email;
  final String password;

  LoginEvent({required this.email, required this.password, required this.context});

  List<Object> get props => [email, password, context];
}

class RegistrationEvent extends AuthEvent {
  final BuildContext context;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String name;
  final String surname;

  RegistrationEvent(
      {required this.email,
      required this.password,
      required this.name,
      required this.surname,
      required this.context});

  List<Object> get props => [email, password, name, surname, context];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things here.

First off, I would create a separate Bloc/Cubit for handling system theme as that is in no way related to Authentication.

Second, you have this odd mix of the current Bloc API and the `mapEventToState` API that has been deprecated for over a year now.

So although its unrelated to your question, I suggest using the Bloc the way its intended to be used to get the most out of it. That would entail actually using all of those `on<Event>((event, emit) async {})` empty event handlers you have and get rid of the `mapEventToState`.

Quick example of that conversion.

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({required this.authRepo}) : super(AuthInitial()) {
    authRepo.getCookie();
    authRepo.getFirebaseToken();
    _checkAuthenticationStatus();
  
    on<LoggedIn>((event, emit) {
      emit(Authenticated(token: event.token));
    });
    
    on<AppStarted>(_onAppStarted); // added this event handler

    // you should use the rest of these event handlers and remove the mapEventToState method
    on<LogoutEvent>((event, emit) async {});
    on<LoginEvent>((event, emit) async {});
    on<RegistrationEvent>((event, emit) async {});
  }

  /// Example event handler method based on what you had in your mapEventToState
  Future<void> _onAppStarted(AppStarted event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    final isAuthenticated = await authRepo.getToken();
    if (isAuthenticated != '') {
      emit(Authenticated(token: isAuthenticated.toString()));
    } else {
      emit(Unauthenticated(token: isAuthenticated.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

As for the Theme aspect. I suggest using [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) so it will persist across restarts without with minimal effort. If you already have another storage solution in place then that works too.

You can create a very simple ThemeCubit class. All it does is update and store the `ThemeMode` which is an enum from the Flutter SDK. This way you keep track of a single `enum` vs 3 separate booleans.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';

class ThemeCubit extends HydratedCubit<ThemeMode> {
  ThemeCubit() : super(ThemeMode.system);

  void updateTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) => emit(themeMode);

  // This handles the restoration of the theme mode when the app is restarted.
  @override
  ThemeMode? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final theme = json['themeMode'];

    switch (theme) {
      case 'ThemeMode.system':
        return ThemeMode.system;
      case 'ThemeMode.light':
        return ThemeMode.light;
      case 'ThemeMode.dark':
        return ThemeMode.dark;
    }
    return ThemeMode.system;
  }

  // This stores the ThemeMode anytime its changed
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(ThemeMode state) {
    return {
      'themeMode': state.toString(),
    };
  }
}
```

Then your material app could look like this

```
class BlocProviderWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlocProviderWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => ThemeCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const App(),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({
    super.key,
  });

  ThemeData _getTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    switch (themeMode) {
      case ThemeMode.system:

        /// Checks system brightness when user selects system theme mode
        final brightness =
            SchedulerBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
        return brightness == Brightness.light
            ? ThemeData.light()
            : ThemeData.dark();

      case ThemeMode.light:
        return ThemeData.light();

      case ThemeMode.dark:
        return ThemeData.dark();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeMode>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: _getTheme(state),
         // ... rest of your Material App
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And last thing specific to HydratedBloc persistence, is initializing the storage in your main function before `runApp`. This requires the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package to get the devices storage directory.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // from path provider

  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: directory,
  );

  
// ...the rest of your startup logic
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such a great explanation, I will definitely implement this in my code

Comment: If I want to change colors of some custom widget, where should I put this colors and how to access them through this cubit?